# React export to CSV - but headers should be in rows

Tags: reactjs

I want to export metadata from react. I'am using react-csv. When i click in export i download file like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByX8c.png)

```
            <CSVLink
              data={metaData}
              headers={headers}
              filename="Metadat222a.csv"
              separator={';'}
              className="test"
              target="_blank"
            >
              {t('Export')}
            </CSVLink>
```

```
 const headers = [
    { label: 'Label', key: 'label' },
    { label: 'Value', key: 'value' },
  ];

  const metaData = data.metadata.map((mData) => {
    return { label: mData.label, value: mData.value };
  });
```

I want to download this file like label and value should be in rows and other data should be in column.
Thaks for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 const metaData = data.metadata.map((mData) => {
return [[mData.label].join(' , '), [mData.value].join(' , ')];
  });



const transposeData = (dataa: string[][]) => {
    return dataa[0].map((_, i) => dataa.map((row) => row[i]));
  };

  const transposedData = transposeData(metaData);
```

Ready!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).